# I need help in assigning trailer compartments to animals

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, web, frontend

We have 4 compartments in a trailer:

`var Compartments = [240, 240, 200, 180];`

Now, We have to assign compartments to the animals for e.g.: Bulls are high in quantity so they have required 2 compartments (that I already have calculated by %)

```
var TotalLoadWeight = parseInt(bullWeight) + parseInt(cowWeight) + parseInt(calfWeight);
var bullperc = parseInt(bullWeight / TotalLoadWeight * 100);
var cowperc = parseInt(calfWeight / TotalLoadWeight * 100);
var calfperc = parseInt(calfWeight / TotalLoadWeight * 100);

var bullCompartment = Math.round(bullperc / 100 * 4); // 2
var cowCompartment = Math.round(cowperc / 100 * 4); // 1
var calfCompartment = Math.round(calfperc / 100 * 4); // 1

var compAllocate = [bullCompartment, cowCompartment, calfCompartment];
```

Problem Statement:
Answer should be - Bull will take 240 & 240; Cow will take 200; Calf will take 180, but I am not getting this answer.
More details: Assign first two compartments to Bull (because Bull count is 2) & those compartments will not repeat for next two.

```
for(var x = 0; x < compAllocate.length; x++{
    for(var i = 0; i < compAllocated[x]; i++){
        console.log("Compartments" + Compartments[x]); // Not getting proper answer.
    }
}
```

These loops are repeating: compartment 1 & 2 for bull, again compartment 1 for cow

Comment: i think you missed something?  do you have a price or something else to optimize? an please separate what you have and what you like to get.

Comment: No, there are no price & all.
I just want to no. of animals puts in trailer compartments

Comment: I have added more info.